# How to get the accumulated sum over time for each group?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, cumulative-sum

I'm working with my personal music history data in which each row in the DataFrame corresponds to a single song that has been listened to. I'd like to structure the data into a DataFrame so that each artist is its own row, while each column should correspond to a unique date. The values in the cells should correspond to the accumulated amount of listens for an artist for a given date.

I am familiar with the groupby method that comes with Pandas, but I am still not entirely sure about how I should structure the data appropriately. I think the logic should be quite the same as in a time series analysis, but I am not that familiar with them yet.

Here's a snippet of the relevant columns of the data set:

```
print(df3[['artist', 'date_time',  'year', 'num_month', 'day']].head(20))

                    artist  date_time  year  num_month  day
0           Porcupine Tree 2019-09-10  2019          9   10
1           Porcupine Tree 2019-09-10  2019          9   10
2           Porcupine Tree 2019-09-09  2019          9   10
3                Rammstein 2019-08-10  2019          9   10
4                     Tool 2019-08-10  2019          9   10
5                     Tool 2019-08-09  2019          9   10
6                     Tool 2019-08-09  2019          9   10
7                     Tool 2019-08-08  2019          9   10
8                     Tool 2019-08-08  2019          9   10
9                     Tool 2019-08-08  2019          9   10
10                    Tool 2019-08-08  2019          9   10
11          Rotting Christ 2019-07-10  2019          9   10
12          Rotting Christ 2019-07-10  2019          9   10
13                  Amoral 2019-06-10  2019          9   10
14  Harry Gregson-Williams 2019-06-10  2019          9   10
15  Harry Gregson-Williams 2019-06-10  2019          9   10
16               Midge Ure 2018-09-10  2019          9   10
17             David Bowie 2018-09-10  2019          9   10
18             David Bowie 2018-09-10  2019          9   10
19             David Bowie 2018-09-10  2019          9   10
```

Note that date_time is of type datetime64[ns]. I also have the day, month and year stored as integers.

Comment: I think you want something like: `df.groupby(['artist', 'date_time']).size().unstack(-1)`?

Comment: Thanks, that is a good start! Your line of code gives the total amount of times that each artist was played for each date. The next step would probably be to iterate over each row in the DataFrame, so that the accumulated sum for a given date is shown instead.

Comment: I added some more rows and included the integer columns (year, num_month, day). The data set is quite big (spanning to the year 2007), so the head only showed the values for the same date. However, I can manually edit them for this example.

Comment: I got it, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(['artist', 'date_time']).size().unstack(-1)
grouped_df = grouped_df.fillna(0)
grouped_df_cumsum = grouped_df.cumsum(axis=1)
```